# how to do some complicate add in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So right now I have more around around 1 million lines of data.

This data contains "**code#**, number of codes"

I would like to make an average of this entire data by 1000 lines. So let me explain this again. I will add number of codes from 'line 1 to 1000' and '1001 to 2000' and '2001 to 3000'.

so far I have this.

```
=SUM(B1:B1000)/1000
```

I want these number to be increase by 1000.

Comment: Put your formula in C1000.  Then highlight C1:C1000 and drag down.  That will put blanks and an average every 1000 cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in a cell in row 1

```
=SUM(INDEX(B:B,(ROW()*1000)-999):INDEX(B:B,(ROW()*1000)))
```

copy down. In row 1 it will sum rows 1 to 1000,

[image]

In row 3 it will sum rows 2001 to 3000, and so on

[image]

Comment: @TaehunAhn I suggest using the `=AVERAGE()` formula instead on `=SUM()/1000`. It just makes it easier and you would be able to use relative referencing so that you can drag the formula.